# Bluetooth not getting connected

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I am very new to Linux and just installed Ubuntu after working with Windows all these years. I cleared my entire windows installation and installed a brand new copy of Ubuntu.

I am trying to add my Bluetooth headset but I am unable to do so, Blueman says Adapter not found. I searched similar things and came up with lots of suggestions from the forum but it is still not working for me.

Here is a screenshot of what I worked out:

[image]

Any help?